# How can I change the save location of the system journal?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd-journald

(for an Arch Linux system) Is it possible to change the storage location of the system journal to a specific directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can be the journal path on a filesystem other than /?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506998/can-be-the-journal-path-on-a-filesystem-other-than)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you mean the location that `journald` writes to, I think not. The configuration file for `journald` is `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`, and the [documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html) for it doesn't list a way to choose locations. You might be able to work around it by making `/var/log/journal` a link to somewhere else, or mount something on that directory.

Comment: Has this change at all since 2014? - I have this problem where my root filesystem is small and out of space and I need to move my journald to /data/

Comment: I don't think so. The linked page is always for the latest version of systemd, and it still doesn't show any relevant option. I think your best option is still to mount something on `/var/log/journal` or its parent directories.